# Is Lehmann-Scheffe an if and only if?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, estimation

That is, if $T$ is UMVUE for $\theta$, does this mean that $T$ is a complete and sufficient statistic for $\theta$?

Comment: I believe the sample median of a sample drawn from the Laplace distribution provides a counter example but it needs to take me more time to write down a rigorous proof. I will come back when I got time.